# Despersion of visible light

Tags: visible-light

I was wondering what is the main point for light despersion through a triangular glass prism?
Why this dispersion occur?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the refractive index of glass is a function of wavelength. So different colors get refracted by different amounts.

Why is the refractive index a function of wavelength? This is a more complex answer... it is related to the way electrons in a solid are harmonic oscillators. Because their amplitude response is a function of frequency, different frequencies of light will "see a different kind of medium". Some long wavelength (low frequency) photons may find the electrons are moving rather easily when excited; the higher frequency (short wavelength) photons find the electrons don't move so well; and that movement of the electrons gives rise to the refractive index difference, and thus to the dispersion (because the angle of refraction is a function of $n$).